# Build list of time delayed function calls within loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a list of function calls separated by a timed interval. The code below currently takes the last item for each function call.

The current code prints: itemThree, itemThree, itemThree - each separated  by ten seconds

The desired code prints: itemOne, itemTwo, itemThree - each separated by ten seconds

```
//Declare variables
var itemList = ["itemOne", "itemTwo", "itemThree"];
var timerInterval = 0;

//Loop through the itemList and build a list of functions calls
//Each function call will be lined up with a 10 second gap
for(index = 0; index < itemList.length; index++) {
    var item = itemList[index]; 
    setTimeout(function() { doSomethingWithItem(item); }, timerInterval);
    timerInterval = timerInterval + 10000;
}

//Print passed in item 
var doSomethingWithItem = function(item) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

I'm trying to make a list of timer delayed function calls. How would I need to change the above code, or is there a better solution? Thanks for yours helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach I use in cases like this is to use an *immediately invoked function expression* in a *pseudo-recursive* loop to extract the elements from the list one at a time:

```
//Declare variables
var itemList = ["itemOne", "itemTwo", "itemThree"];
var timerInterval = 10000;

(function loop() {
    var item = itemList.shift();
    if (item) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            doSomethingWithItem(item);
            loop()
        }, timerInterval);
    }
})();

//Print passed in item 
var doSomethingWithItem = function(item) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

Without the `for` loop you avoid the issue of the `item` variable having its last assigned value during each callback.

With the pseudo-recursive use of `setTimeout` you also avoid queuing more than one timer at a time.  I call this usage *pseudo-recursive* because whilst it may appear that `loop` is calling itself, in reality the `setTimeout` call merely adds callbacks to a queue of functions to be triggered from the browser's event processing loop.

Comment: I like the way you've removed the loop , and the need for multiple timers at once. This seems like what I was looking for, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript passes values *by reference*, and by the time timeout fires, `index` will reach its greatest value and therefore "itemThree" will always be shown. To fix that, you need to create another scope for the looping variable to live in so it doesn't get changed by outer scope.

```
//Loop through the itemList and build a list of functions calls
//Each function call will be lined up with a 10 second gap
for(index = 0; index < itemList.length; index++) {
    // creating new scope for index to live in
    (function(num) {
        var item = itemList[num]; 
        setTimeout(function() { doSomethingWithItem(item); }, timerInterval);
        timerInterval = timerInterval + 10000;
    })(index);
}
```

Comment: I have corrected your indentation to make it clearer for readers, but I think your explanation is rather misleading. Couldn't you use word "_scope_" in your answer?

Comment: Thanks, and the word "scope" can be found in the answer.

Comment: JS does _not_ pass values by reference.  However variables from higher level scopes are _accessed_ by reference rather than obtaining their own copy.